Question on overlapping parbox
I don't understand why the following lines don't overlap properly with a parbox involved. The First Line collapses perfectly, but the Second Line does not. Of course, if parbox is set to [b], the opposite occurs. I don't understand why both lines don't overlap perfectly.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
First Line
\vskip -\baselineskip
\parbox[t]{1in}{\strut First Line\\ Second Line\strut}
\vskip -\baselineskip
Second Line
\end{document}



Your example can be transformed to TeX primitives:
\vtop{First line\par
      Second line (1)\par
}
\vskip-\baselineskip
Second line (2)

The \vtop has a big depth, so the following box with the "Second line (2)" text cannot respect the \baselineskip. The \lineskip is used instead (with default 1pt). The baseline-grid is broken.
The solution is to keep the \prevdepth primitive value at the end of the \vtop and restore it after the \vtop is inserted:
\newdimen\keepdepthdim
\def\keepdepth{\par \global\keepdepthdim=\prevdepth}
\def\restoredepth{\par \prevdepth=\keepdepthdim}

\vtop{First line\par
      Second line (1)\par
      \keepdepth
}
\restoredepth
\vskip-\baselineskip
Second line (2)
\bye

Your LaTeX code should be:
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\keepdepthdim
\def\keepdepth{\par \global\keepdepthdim=\prevdepth}
\def\restoredepth{\par \prevdepth=\keepdepthdim}


\begin{document}
First Line
\vskip -\baselineskip
\parbox[t]{1in}{\strut First Line\\ Second Line\keepdepth}\restoredepth
\vskip -\baselineskip
Second Line
\end{document}


This is perfect! Thank you for the explanation too.

This version uses \parbox[c] so the baseline doesn't work for either the top or bottom.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{First Line}\strut
\vskip-\baselineskip\hrule height0pt
\parbox[c]{1in}{\strut First Line\\ Second Line\strut}
\hrule height0pt\vskip-\baselineskip
\strut\textcolor{red}{Second Line}
\end{document}


An even simpler solution is to not use a \parbox, unless you want to put text into an unbreakable box.  Anything else can be done with a group.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{First Line}
\vskip-\baselineskip
{\rightskip=\dimexpr \textwidth-1in\relax
First Line\\ Second Line}%
\vskip-\baselineskip
\textcolor{red}{Second Line}
\end{document}

